# Изменение лейблов

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток.
На одну из кнопок стоит событие(создание массива очередей,количество элементов в которых выводится на лейблы),которое включает следующий блок кода:

```
{
        Random rnd = new Random();
        M = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); //Количество очередей
        QArray = new Queue<int>[M];
        int [] Array = new int[30];
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Array[i] = i + 1; 
        }
        int ArrayCount = 30;
        int MaximumValue;
        int element;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {

            {
                MaximumValue = 0;
                QArray[i] = new Queue<int>();
                int count = rnd.Next(1, 8); //Количество элементов в очереди
                for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
                {
                    if (ArrayCount > 0)
                    {
                        if (MaximumValue == 30) break;
                        element = rnd.Next(0, 30);
                        do
                        {
                            element = rnd.Next(0, 30);
                            if (Array[element] < MaximumValue) continue;
                        } while (Array[element] == 0);
                        MaximumValue = Array[element];
                        Array[element] = 0;
                        QArray[i].Enqueue(Array[element]);
                        ArrayCount--;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (MaximumValue > MaximumofM) MaximumofM = MaximumValue;
            labelArray = new Label[M];
            labelArray[i] = new Label();
            labelArray[i].Location = new Point(30 + 40 * i, 100);
            labelArray[i].Text = QArray[i].Count.ToString();
            labelArray[i].Size = new Size(25, 15);
            this.Controls.Add(labelArray[i]);

        }

    }
```

По нажатию другой кнопки в одну из очередей массива происходит добавление элемента,таким образом значение на лейблах должно измениться. Код представленный ниже должен был бы зановы вывести все лейблы, но они не изменяются. Подскажите как поменять теперь значения в лейблах? Заранее спасибо

```
int add=rnd.Next(0, M+1);
QArray[add].Enqueue(MaximumofM);
for (int i=0;i< M; i++)
{
    labelArray[i] = new Label();
    labelArray[i].Text = QArray[i].Count.ToString(); //Количество элементов в очереди
    labelArray[i].Location = new Point(30 + 40 * i, 100);
    labelArray[i].Size = new Size(25, 15);
}
```

Comment: Дважды прочел Ваш вопрос, но так и не смог его понять. Есть чем его дополнить, чтобы стало понятнее? Может скриншоты добавите?

Comment: @DenisBubnov  При нажатии на кнопку добавить элемент в очередь данные об очередях должны измениться(количество элементов в одной должно стать больше) динамически,т.е. текст в лейблах должен поменяться, но этого не происходит,как этого добиться?

Comment: `labelArray[i] = new Label();` - уберите эту строчку из второго фрагмента кода

Comment: @DenisBubnov Тогда в этом месте появится исключение " Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: убрать строку @Igor предлагает :) но мне, как и ему тоже кажется, что она лишняя. Так как это все же новый объект, а не существующий старый.

Comment: добавьте немного больше кода, чтобы было понятно, где у Вас объявлен `labelArray` и в каких методах лежит тот или иной код. Просто так не совсем понятно...

Comment: @DenisBubnov Проблема на самом деле в коде,задающем очереди,написан ужасно,если сможете помогите разобраться,что можно исправить,у самого не получается.Проблема в том,что я использую стандартную Queue в c#, создаю массив из M таких очередей,затем заполняю каждую очередь элементами(от 1 до 30),причем,элемент меньше чем наибольший элемент очереди туда попасть не может.Для этого я завел массив со значениями от 1 до 30 и обнулял,если какой-то номер уже оказался в очереди(чтобы номера не повторялись).Затем выводил значение количества элементов на лейблы.

Comment: @DenisBubnov некоторые очереди оставались пустые и при обращении к ним возникает исключение,которое я указывал выше.

Comment: @DenisBubnov добавил код полностью выше,в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int add=rnd.Next(0, M+1);
QArray[add].Enqueue(MaximumofM);
labelArray[add].Text = QArray[add].Count.ToString(); // цикл не нужен
```

Comment: При таком коде генерируется исключение "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.".

Comment: Научитесь пользоваться отладчиком. Исключение на какой строке, какие значения переменных, использованных в коде этой строки?

Comment: Разобрался,спасибо.